# How do I delete the files in a directory after I have converted them from XML to Txt using a Visual C# console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, delete-file

I am creating a Visual C# application to covert xml files to x12 edi txt files. I would like to delete all the files in the xml directory after I have created their txt equivalents. I have tried adding a foreach method with file.delete, but cannot get it to work. When I place it within the main method, I am told the file is in use. When I place it outside of the main method, it is not executed at all. Below is the code for my application with the file.delete at the end, outside of the main method and class.

```
namespace XMLParse
{
     class Class1
    {

    public static void Main()
    {

        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\onlinesales");
        foreach (string filename in Files)
        {

            StringBuilder orderid = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder ordernumber = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder staddress = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder city = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder state = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder zip = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder country = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder email = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder partnumber = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder quantity = new StringBuilder();


            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(filename)))
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderID");
                orderid.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("OrderNumber");
                ordernumber.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("Name");
                name.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("Line1");
                staddress.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("City");
                city.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("StateProvinceCode");
                state.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("PostalCode");
                zip.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("CountryCode");
                country.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("Email");
                email.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("ProductSKU");
                partnumber.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                reader.ReadToFollowing("Quantity");
                quantity.Append(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

            }

            using (StreamWriter fileout =
                new StreamWriter("W:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-ff") + ".txt", false, Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                fileout.WriteLine("ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*daisywebstore  *12*5016361200     *" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd") + "*1559*U*00400*000001649*0*P>~");
                fileout.WriteLine("GS*PO*daisywebstore*5016361200*" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "*" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + "*1649*X*004010~");
                fileout.WriteLine("ST*850*13~");
                fileout.WriteLine("BEG*00*SA*08272226001*" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "~");
                fileout.WriteLine("REF*DP*089~");
                fileout.WriteLine("DTM*002*20120104~");
                fileout.WriteLine("N1*ST*" + name + "~");
                fileout.WriteLine("N3*" + staddress + "~");
                fileout.WriteLine("N4*" + city + "*" + state + "*" + zip + "~");
                fileout.WriteLine("N1*RE**92*00103653341~");
                fileout.WriteLine("PO1*1*6*EA*33.28*TE*IN*985880-542~");
                fileout.WriteLine("PID*F*****CO2 BB PISTOL     $ 5693~");
                fileout.WriteLine("PO4*3*1*EA~");
                fileout.WriteLine("CT*1~");
                fileout.WriteLine("AMT*1*199.68~");
                fileout.WriteLine("SE*16*13~");
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
 public class Delete
{
 private static void Empty()
   {
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\onlinesales");
    foreach (string filename in files)
        File.Delete(filename);

   }
  }
```

Comment: You're not calling the method from anywhere.

Comment: `When I place it outside of the main method, it is not executed at all.` Where are you calling the method?

Comment: I believe I am beginning to see. I need to call the Empty method within the Main method, correct? Will this not produce the same 'file is being used' error I receive when leaving the foreach method within the Main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the `XMLReader` through `using` but the `StreamReader` is still open which is causing this error

try this

```
foreach (string filename in Files)
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(filename);
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(read))
            {
            }
    read.Close();
}
```

or

```
 foreach (string filename in Files)
 {
      using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(read))
                {
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: I'd bet that calling XmlReader.Dispose actually calls the Dispose method on the StreamReader, and that in turn calls Dispose on the Stream.

Comment: Try that in a example and see what happens

Comment: I am still receiving the 'cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process error.

Comment: After cleaning up my code a bit, making certain that had the second for each in the right place and placing the stream reader in a foreach statement, it is now working. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this overload of the StreamReader constructor instead:

```
new StreamReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
```

Comment: This does delete the files, but not before the new files are finished being created. I then get a file handler exception saying file cannot be found.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see where that could be happening. Is there some more code?

Comment: My apologies. This happens when I add this overload as well as placing the foreach file.delete in the main method. When I remove the foreach method and leave the new overload, the new files are generated, as desired, but the old files are not deleted.

Comment: Okay, I think you need to rework the code a little. Firstly, take the declarations of the StringBuilders outside the foreach. Only delete the file after all the rest of the code is done with it, in a new foreach loop if you need to.

Comment: Removing the StringBuilder declarations from the foreach made the information from the xml files compile in the the string, so that file 2 had the info from files 1 & 2 and so on. On the plus side, I have fixed it now. Placing the streamreader in a using statement was the first step.  Then, with some house cleaning I was able to get the new foreach into the correct method and delete the files. Thank you for your time. As a solo developer, the "rubber ducking" really saves me.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `new streameader(filename)` in a using statement as well. assuming the files are saved to another directory; just delete the directory

```
Directory.Delete(@"C:\onlinesales", true);
```

Comment: I need to keep the directory. Even after wrapping it in a using statement I still receive the  'cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process' error.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace XMLParse
{
    class Class1
    {

        public static void Main()
        {

            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\onlinesales");
            foreach (string filename in Files)
            {

                //...YOUR CODE
            }

            //....ADD THIS LINE
            Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\onlinesales\", "*.xml"),
              delegate(string path) { File.Delete(path); });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This produces the same 'cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process' error.

Comment: @TyrelDenison Doesn't using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(filename)))
            {....} releases (Disposes) the object automatically after it out of scope? (I'm not sure, but as i remember it does. Of course if you not using "using", you should close and set the object to NULL in order GC clears it ASAP.

Comment: To my knowledge yes, it should be releasing it when it is out of scope. Several have suggested that StreamReader is still open and holding the files, and they suggested wrapping it in a using statement as well. Even after doing this I receive the same error. I had not considered using a GC because I was under the impression it was not reliable for an immediate need. Is this not so?

Comment: OK, if so, try to remove using and do reader.Close();reader = null; I will test it myself later.

Comment: After wrapping streamreader in a using statement and cleaning up my code, I was able to get everything set. Thanks.